# Why do we know that , besides the known idoneal numbers , there is at most one more?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idoneal_number

the definition of an idoneal number is given : A number $n$ is idoneal if there are no integers $a,b,c$ with $0<a<b<c$ and $n=ab+ac+bc$

A proof is mentioned that, besides the known idoneal numbers, there is at most one more.

> Does anyone know this proof and can explain the main ideas ?
>
> What can be said about the missing number, assuming the list is incomplete ? (for example : do we know an upper bound ?)

Comment: The proof by Weinberger is a pdf link at the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Take a look and see for yourself

Comment: OK, I will read the link.

Comment: Indeed lots of people suggest you pretty much ignore Wikipedia articles and just scroll all the way to the bottom. Some of the lousiest articles on Wikipedia have the best sources.